# differential equation - spring

Tags: physics, differential

2y'' + 5y' + 3y = x + cos(x)

Given that the differential equation represents a mass on a spring with friction, qualitatively rate the spring as weak or strong (in relation to friction). Justify your choice based on your solution.

my work: To start, I looked at this equation and reflected it onto the equation: mx''+cx'+kx = F(t) where m is mass, c is the damping constant, k is the spring constant, and F(t) is the external force. In the case of our equation, m = 2, c = 5, k = 3, and F(t) = x+cos(x).

However, I am unsure of how to proceed after this in order to find out whether the spring is weak or strong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does $t$ have to do with $x+\cos(x)$?

Comment: Determine whether the system is underdamped, critically damped, or overdamped.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation of homogeneous part $2y''+5y'+3y=0$ is
$$2\lambda^2+5\lambda+3=0$$
has roots $\lambda_2=-\dfrac32<-1=\lambda_1<0$ which shows that the system has any oscillation. With initial condition $y_0$ the solution is 
$$y(x)=y_0\left(3e^{-x}-2e^{-\frac32x}\right)$$

Comment: I had gotten the solution beforehand, but I'm confused as to what that tells us about the spring compared to friction?

Comment: @interestedinmath Apparently the force $x+\cos x$ shows that the spring will extend to infinity !